# Backdrop-filter ignores blur value on stacked elements in forefront

Tags: html, css, blur, css-filters, gaussianblur

The smallest innermost circle in the snippet below has a `backdrop-filter` blur of `10rem` that's not being applied. It looks like the `span` element is inheriting the same exact amount of blur from it's parent instead of taking the higher value that should be applied. Any idea why and/or have any known workarounds?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body, section {
  height: 100%;
}
section, div, span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: 
    url(
      'https://media.giphy.com/media/MjHdjmbIFQuDHRkGbI/giphy.gif'
    );
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
div, span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10rem; height: 10rem;
  background-color: rgba( 80%,100%,90%,0.1 );
  background-image: none;
  backdrop-filter: blur( 0.375rem );
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 0.375rem );  
}
span {
  width: 5rem; height: 5rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur( 10rem ); /* this gets ignored */
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 10rem ); /* 10rem blur isn't applied, why? */
}
```

```html
<section> <div> <span></span> </div> </section>
```

`10rem` blur would blur the innermost circle significantly more than is being seen in this example. I'm viewing this in **Chrome**.

**Overall goal here is to make the innermost circle *more* blurry than the div it's inside of. How do I accomplish this?**

Comment: no, it doesn't work that way. What you have is logical because the blur of the span will only apply to element that are behind it and inside the div. Any element outside the div will get affect by the filter of the div only

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am trying to make the span in the middle more blurry than the div it's inside of. Can this be achieved with backdrop-filter? Perhaps by removing the span outside of the div and absolutely positioning it on top? I doubt it though :(, feel like I've tried that before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't nest the elements, keep them separate.

Here is another idea to achieve what you want

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://media.giphy.com/media/MjHdjmbIFQuDHRkGbI/giphy.gif');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

section * {
  border-radius: 50%;
  grid-area:1/1; /* make both overlap */
  margin:auto; /* and center them */
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: rgba( 80%, 100%, 90%, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 0.375rem);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 0.375rem);
}
section div {
  /* make a hole in the div for the span */
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,#0000 calc(100% - 2.5rem),#000 0);
}

section span {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur( 2rem);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 2rem);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>  </div>
  <span></span>
</section>
```

Comment: @devsandbox it does give a different result without mask. With mask you make both independent since there is no intersection. With mask you have an intersection and a cumulative filter